# Is it recommended to test complex ASP.NET UI workflows using JMETER for performance tests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

We have developed Asp.NET application .It is automated Inventory Based System to place orders and shipped it to customer. There are no REST API. It contains UI and API layer. We need to do performance test using JMETER with 1000 users who will create inventory, create orders, create items, ship it to customer. We are doing feasibility study with JMETER. Using JMETER, I record Create Order workflow on FireFox. On UI, I performed 10-20 actions. These gets recorded in JMETER. However, for 20 actions, I can see more than 50 recorded HTTP requests. These are APIs which gets called internally.

Also, note that only record and play is not going to work. I need to store unique order Ids, read data from CSV etc. etc. So it requires lots of efforts also.

Is it recommended to do such performance test using JMETER. UI changes, flow changes or any change made by developer in code like JSON format, GET/POST data might affect my scripts ?

[image: Sample Recorded Script]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter **can** be used for any web application performance testing, no matter which technology is being used under the hood.

1. With regards to handling dynamic elements, as far as I'm aware only LoadRunner provides [automatic correlation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.56/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/Correlation/AutomaticCorrelation.htm) out of the box. You can achieve similar with JMeter by using alternative recording solution, see [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.
2. For tests parameterization (using data from CSV or database) - it will be up to you, no matter which tool you're using.
3. For changing logic you will need to amend/re-create your test, no matter which tool you're using.

So it doesn't really matter which tool you will be using, you will have to handle the same set of problems. If you don't have other tool(s) in inventory - JMeter a good tool (if not the best). Just remember that your test must represent real user as close as possible, otherwise it will not make sense.

Comment: Correct. Thanks. However, is it recommended to do performance test for such  application ? For 5 UI actions, I can see almost 40 recorded HTTP requests because these are ASP.NET APIs called internally. Changes in POST data, UI will affect JMEETR scripts badly